# apply unique index only on non-empty string column

Tags: postgresql, grails-orm

I have a string column inside my Postgres DB, which has a unique index, but I want to allow duplicate values in some rows when the column is empty.

I want my unique index to allow empty values. How can I do that?

Current code for my postgres model:

```
my_field string `gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
```

Comment: Its not possible to create a unique index and have same duplicate value in some column at the same time, either try by creating a index and performing *index only scan* to check whether the value is present or not

Answer (score 3):

You can create a partial index:

```
create unique index on the_table (the_column)
where the_column <> '';
```

Depending on your requirements you might also want to exclude rows where `the_column` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a unique index if you treat empty strings as NULL values:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON mytab (nullif(my_field, ''));
```

This works because unique indexes allow storing multiple NULL values.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried so much to make this index using the Gorm, but failed :(. it lead to syntax error. Do you know how should i write it as a gorm index?

Comment: I have never heard of Gorm. Use SQL when you talk to a database.